# xslt copy only certain descendants

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copy some descendant elements without a certain attribute. I cant figure out the right way to do this.

Here the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<itemlist>
   <item>
      <subitem id="g0b86bn6"/>
      <subitem>
         <subitem/>
         <subitem id="8967698"/>
      </subitem>
      <subitem>
         <subitem/>
         <subitem id="9868966n7"/>
         <subitem>
           <subitem id="9896"/>
         <subitem>
      </subitem>
   </item>
</itemlist>
```

The elements could be nested arbirtarily deep.

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<itemlist>
   <item>
      <subitem>
         <subitem/>
      </subitem>
      <subitem>
         <subitem/>
      </subitem>
   </item>
</itemlist>
```

My xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
            <xsl:if test=".[not(@id)]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem: It only copies the children, not the descendants. And copy-of also copies the descendants that I dont want to copy.

How should I do this? Thanks for help and tips!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What are the **exact** conditions for removing an element? Is it just the existence of an `id` attribute? If so, your result does not match your intent.  --  Note also that your input is not well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred strategy in cases like these is to use the *identity transform template* to copy everything *as is*, then add exception templates to suppress nodes you do **not** want to be passed to the output. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subitem[@id]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following well-formed input:

**XML**

```
<itemlist>
  <item>
    <subitem id="g0b86bn6"/>
    <subitem>
      <subitem/>
      <subitem id="8967698"/>
    </subitem>
    <subitem>
      <subitem/>
      <subitem id="9868966n7"/>
      <subitem>
        <subitem id="9896"/>
      </subitem>
    </subitem>
  </item>
</itemlist>
```

will suppress any `subitem` element that has an `id` attribute, resulting in:

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<itemlist>
  <item>
    <subitem>
      <subitem/>
    </subitem>
    <subitem>
      <subitem/>
      <subitem/>
    </subitem>
  </item>
</itemlist>
```